# Laurent Series Partial Fractions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I have $\frac{1}{z+z^2}$ defined on the annulus $|z+1|>1$.

I write:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z+1} = -\frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{(z+1)-1} = -\frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{z+1} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z+1}} = -\frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{z+1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z+1)^{-n} = -(z+1)^{-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z+1)^{-n-1} = -(z+1)^{-1} + \sum_{n \leq -1}^{}(z+1)^{n} = \sum_{n \leq -2}^{}(z+1)^{n}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good.    I forgot you want $\mid z+1\mid \gt1.$

Comment: @insomesense What do you mean?

Comment: I answered but deleted when I realized my mistake.  It's slightly simpler on $\mid z+1\mid\lt1.$

Comment: @insomesense Okay thanks for your help.